# (iOS) How do I check an iPhone's paired Bluetooth devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

I want to use CoreBluetooth (as my app must be eligible for the App Store) to check all of the currently paired and connected Bluetooth devices. This should not require any Bluetooth scanning, right? I just want to see what the system is paired with. If I can't do that, a scan is the second option.

What I'm trying is not working. It says that Bluetooth is not powered on and crashes, but the CBCentralManager's state is on! Any ideas on how to fix this, or am I totally off track?

All of this in ViewController for now:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [self.centralManager retrieveConnectedPeripherals]; //makes the system call didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals{
    NSLog(@"didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals called");
    for (CBPeripheral *a in peripherals){
        NSLog(a.name); //just log the name for now to see if it recognized it
    } //but it never ends up logging anything, and I have a BT keyboard paired/connected with the iPhone 5
} //and I get an error at some point, <CBConcreteCentralManager: 0x71ab020> is not powered on

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)manager{
    if ([manager state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff");
    if ([manager state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn"); //this is what gets logged when I run it on an iPhone 5
    if ([manager state] == CBCentralManagerStateResetting) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStateResetting");
    if ([manager state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized");
    if ([manager state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStateUnknown");
    if ([manager state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this also, and hopefully some of what I've learned will help.

Couple of things:

1) You're likely getting the "Bluetooth not powered on" error because you're calling `[self.central retrieveConnectedPeripherals]` immediately after initializing the CBCentralManager.  You need to give the CBCentralManager enough time to connect to the bluetooth hardware.

Try this instead,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
}
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)manager {
   switch (manager.state) {
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
             NSLog(@"CBCentral Manager powered on");
             [self.centralManager retrieveConnectedPeripherals];
             break;
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
             ...etc.
}
```

Also, be aware that CBCentralManager works for iOS devices with Bluetooth 4.0.  Currently, Bluetooth 4 is installed on iPhone 4S/5, iPod 4, and iPad 3/4/mini.  So, be aware that your App will not work on iPad 1/2, iPhone 2/3, and iPod 2/3.

Still figuring this out, but it is also possible that you may not see your keyboard because it is not a Bluetooth 4 device.  Let me know what you find out.