# Check if there is any bluetooth device paired to iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

In my application, I want to check if there is any bluetooth device paired to the phone. Is there a way to know that? I don't want to know a specific device, just if the phone is paired.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162518/ios-how-do-i-check-an-iphones-paired-bluetooth-devices